# Caching SSD on laptop with SSD fisk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, cache

I have a laptop (Asus N551JW) which came with builtin HDD of 1TB and a small caching Kingstone SSD of, i think, 64 MB. That configuration makes sense as HDD should benefit from SSD cache. 
As i already had my good old Samsung 830 SSD (256 GB) i decided to replace my built in HDD.

Now, the problem is i'm not sure if i should disable that "man-in-the-middle" caching SSD in order to gain performances? My guess is that, if caching SSD has worse performance than my 830, it would give more harm than use.

Can you please tell me if disabling the cache would provide some performance benefits?

P.S. as i'm using Arch linux i tested my SSD read speed like this:

```
#hdparm -t /dev/sda
```

and i got this result:

```
Timing buffered disk reads: 774 MB in  3.01 seconds = 257.38 MB/sec
```

Result is with cache enabled. SSD is connected to Sata 3 port (where my HDD used to be) but i'm sure it should provide more than 257 MB/sec

Comment: Was that speed test with or without the cache SSD enabled?

Comment: With cache enabled (answer edited)

Comment: What are your results when the cache is disabled?  That should answer your question once you see.

Comment: Well i can't disable it without opening my laptop and disconnecting it physically (and i wanted to avoid that without consulting here as i guessed somebody else maybe had the same question once :) )